# Edit and Delete option in Div Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `ul` consisting of several `li`'s in it. Now I wanted to add `Edit` And `Delete` option infront of every `li` so that it can be Edited or Deleted on click.

How can i do this ?

Thanks in Advance for any help :)

Comment: You shouldn't have any inline JavaScript for security purposes. Additionally, we need to see the JavaScript functions.

Comment: I have written simple delete function, but it does not delete li within code.

Comment: So for edit how you want to put textbox?

Comment: @ram yes a text box will do that will edit the given li. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X33px/2/)**

```
$('ul li').each(function () {
    $(this).append('<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>  <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>')
});
$('ul li a.delete').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
$('ul li a.edit').on('click', function () {
    var val = $(this).siblings('span').html();
    if (val) {
        $(this).parent().prepend('<input type="text" class="txt" value="' + val + '" />');
        $(this).siblings('span').remove();
        $(this).html('Update');
    } else {
        var $txt = $(this).siblings().filter(function() { return $(this).hasClass('txt') });
        $(this).parent().prepend('<span class="lead justified">' + $txt.val() + '</span>');
        $txt.remove();
        $(this).html('Edit');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Well it is appending but not to given li,i tried specifying ul class name in first line but still not working :(

Comment: @RS26 can you make it clear what is not working? Did you checked the fiddle sample..?

Comment: Yes i did, and it is working fine in fiddle. But when i implement it in my code, delete and edit option are placed in Navigation Bar instead of being placed infront of li

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS trick to perform `inplace edit` on span's and [`jQuery#remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) for deleting `li's`.

Idea is to hide the text when `Edit` is clicked and show `textbox` and vice-versa on click of `Delete`.

```
$('button.edit').click(function(){        
    var label_element = $(this).parent().find('span'),
        input_element = $(this).parent().find('input');
    label_element.addClass('editing');        
    input_element.val(label_element.text());
    input_element.addClass('editing');
});
$('button.delete').click(function(){        
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
 $('input').blur(function(){        
    var label_element = $(this).parent().find('span');
    label_element.text($(this).val());
    $(this).removeClass('editing');
    label_element.removeClass('editing'); 

});
```

**[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/b38XJ/)**

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you use **[Jquery](http://jquery.com/)** or another [library](http://microjs.com/#) to handle cross browser issues. Anyway, here is the solution with pure javascript... it should work in all [modern browsers](http://browsehappy.com/) recent versions.

### [SOLUTION DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yaxen/1/edit)

#### HTML

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li>
    <span> BE/ BTech/ MCS </span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> Solid </span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> Strong </span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> Sharp </span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> Ability</span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> Deal problems</span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> Strong </span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> Excellent </span>
    <button class="remove">Delete</button>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### JS

```
var removeClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

for(var i = 0; i < removeClassElements.length; i++){
  var element = removeClassElements[i];  
  element.addEventListener('click', remove);
}

var editClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');

for(var i = 0; i < editClassElements.length; i++){
  var element = editClassElements[i];  
  element.addEventListener('click', edit);
}

function remove() {
  var li = this.parentNode;
  var ul = li.parentNode;  
  ul.removeChild(li);
}

function edit() {
  var li = this.parentNode;
  var span = li.children[0];
  span.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  span.focus();
}
```

PS: You don't need `class="lead justified"` in each li element. You can use a **CSS** rule like this:

```
.fa-ul li span:first-child {...}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly in JS fiddle, but when i implement it in my code it says removeClassElements is undefined. Thanks

Comment: Are you running all the code in the same context? Do you have separate files? Are you using frames or iframes?

Comment: I am running all the code in same context , no separate files.And i am not using frames or iframes.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo error? If so, try debuging using `console.log(removeClassElements);` after the variable declaration. It  should display the elements in the dev console (F12).

Comment: Created JS fiddle and this is how it is working http://jsfiddle.net/srahil33/wN23b/

Comment: I changed my mind and wanted a complete div to get editable on single click instead of editing single single list item, and i got it working using jquery. Would you help me one more thing??

Comment: sure ... but if it's a different subject you should create another question.

Comment: I have created another question, will you have a look at it please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657009/edit-div-and-have-updated-information-on-page-reload

Comment: Please help sir, i am not getting how to do it

Comment: take a look here: http://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="lead justified"> BE/ BTech/ MCS </span><a href="#" onclick="remove()">Delete</a><a href="#" onclick="edit(this)">Edit</a></li>...
```

The function `edit(this)` is given incorrectly and `this` links to `<a>Edit</a>`.
You should add `id` property to the `<span>`.

```
<li><span class="lead justified" id="foo"> BE/ BTech/ MCS </span><a href="#" onclick="remove()">Delete</a><a href="#" onclick="edit(foo)">Edit</a></li>

<script>
function edit(target) {
     target.contenteditable = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need do change some changes in your markups, You can take `<div>` instead of `<span>` and can apply HTML5's attribute [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Sample Markup

```
<li>
    <div class="lead justified">BE/ BTech/ MCS</div>
    <a href="#" onclick="remove(this)">Delete</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="edit(this)">Edit</a>
</li>
```

**Script**

*Edit*

```
function edit(elem){
    $(elem).siblings('div.lead').attr('contenteditable',true);
}
```

*Delete*

```
function remove(elem){   
    $(elem).closest('li').remove(); // Deletes li
    return false;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DLMMj/1/)

Comment: It does edit, but there is no way i can save it :( Once i click edit, it stays editable only. And anyway i can show it in text box when i click on edit.

Comment: @RS26 You can definately save the value of that div