# Edit div and have updated information on page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have posted div which can be edited or deleted.Take a look at given link

Here is the [JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/MMzYJ/8)

Now i want the original code in `html to get updated` and show updated information on page refresh/reload after `Edit` or `Delete` operation is performed.

Thanks for help.

Comment: No down vote please. If you fell it is wrong question i will edit/delete it.Thanks

Comment: question too ambiguous, what html to get updated? you want to store origonal values that were there Before Edit/Delete?? more information / post code + what you've tried. I always undo downvotes after edits to make them clearer bud.

Comment: Html within div should get updated.No i don't to store original values that were there before .If you had a look at js fiddle,after clicking edit,div elements can be edited.Now after editing i want the edited thing to take place in my original html code too. Thanks

Comment: When you say "in my origonal html" you mean so that when page is reloaded it will have updated information?

Comment: Yes that's totally what i wanted to say sir:)

Comment: You'll need to store the values in a database or something.. what kinda backend/framework are you using?

Comment: Asking about Db, i am SQL DB as backend

Comment: Waiting for your help sir :)

Comment: ok - i suggest on your `done` button click, use jquery ajax https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to send the input from the user (escaped using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) to the db.. then encoding it again on the page load when you fill your div with the saved data from the DB.. I cant really help you with that though, maybe that gives you an idea/start though?

Comment: few notes though - use a parametrised stored procedure to store the html in the database ..  otherwise you'll be vulnerable to sql injection (https://www.google.de/search?q=sql+injection+prevention&oq=sql+injection+prevention&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3848j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks a lot,that will definitely help me to start up.Thanks for help

Comment: Alright, Thanks @RS26. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: Hey there RS26, this a good resource for you to start http://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saving input from the User and showing on page load**

I suggest on your `done` button click, use jquery ajax api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax to send the input from the user (escaped using stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/…) to the db.. then encoding it again on the page load when you fill your div with the saved data from the DB..

few notes though - use a parametrised stored procedure to store the html in the database .. otherwise you'll be vulnerable to sql injection (google.de/…) –